# Tomcat HTTPS ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap godaddy

Tags: java, tomcat, keytool

I just wanna change the Tomcat SSL certificates. Issued on GoDaddy.
We run these commands:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore gvia.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdroot-g2.crt
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore gvia.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore gvia.keystore -trustcacerts -file gvia.cert
```

Just normal i changed the server.xml and add:

```
<Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/home/gv14pr0d/ssl_helper/2019/gvia.keystore" keystorePass="*****"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I restart the server and on the browser i get:

```
no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

We just follow the instructions of the panel.

Version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This can mean the server has no private key. Did you import the signed certificate using the same alias as the key pair?

Comment: The gvia.pem or the gvia.key?